# jquery reports this error only on server. $ is not defined [Break On This Error] $(document).ready(function() {

Tags: jquery, localhost

On my localhost it works perfect. And when I upload the script on server it gives me this error.

$ is not defined [Break On This Error] $(document).ready(function() {

How can it works on my localhost and not on server?

Comment: Because you also have to upload the jQuery file to the server.. Online pages cannot load resources from the `file://` protocol.

Comment: As simple as that, it is not able to find the jquery path.

Comment: I had this error persist for a long time with no apparent reason. I switched to Google CDN for jQuery and that fixed it. I guess my file was corrupted somehow in upload.

Comment: jquery file is on server. I uploaded complete directory where website is placed. can it be related with permissions? and jquery is working in other parts of the page. It just don't work when I try to use $.get. in that part I'm giving the other page data. and when I try to read that data, I can read only first one.

Comment: anyone have an idea? in JS file I can see all variables ok. but when I send it with $.get to php script, it shows only first one. this is the piece of code for that

$.get("js/shop/shopAjax.php",
   {
    order:1,
    img: img,
    price: price,
    title: title
   }

Comment: We really would need to see your HTML/JS to have any idea how to proceed.

Comment: I figured it out. the error was (I have no idea why), because I used mysql_real_escape_string on elements that I was receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. the error was (I have no idea why), because I used mysql_real_escape_string on elements that I was receiving